# pmin gives the wrong answer

Tags: r, dataframe

`pmin` does not return the appropriate output in the following example.

```
eps <- 1e-16
x <- structure(list(X = c(0.219801587301587, 0.340792857142857, 0.398129365079365, 
                      1, 1, 0.853353968253968, 0.930726984126984, 0.980263131313131, 
                      0.968269047619047, 0.953053336369513, 1, 1, 1, 0.951969003219003, 
                      0.91514335177894, 0.884824997224998, 0.884824997224998, 0.884824997224998 )), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = "data.frame", .Names = "X")

pmin(x, 1 - eps)
```

The function incorrectly returns `NA` where the value of `x` is 1. Should this be reported as a bug?

Comment: This seems like an odd result at best and I confirm I get the same thing. Something like `pmin(data.frame(a=1:3,b=3:5), 1)` makes little sense to me, particularly when `pmin(data.frame(a=1:3,b=3:5), 1:3)` errors out. Doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: Let's really break it - `pmin(data.frame(a=1:3,b=3:5), data.frame(a=c(1,1,1)))`

Comment: Hint: you're looking for `do.call`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured out that this is because `x` is a `data.frame` and pmin is expecting a vector. So the following works just fine:

```
pmin(x[,1], 1 - eps)
```

But I wanted to understand why it wasn't working for `data.frame`. So going through the code for `pmin` the offending line is the following:

```
mmm[change] <- each[change]
```

because `each` refers to the constant (`1 - eps` in this case) and `change` is a logical vector anything other than `each[1]` will return `NA`. Whereas the case where `x` is a vector executes at the beginning of the function at:

```
  if (all(vapply(elts, function(x) is.atomic(x) && !is.object(x), NA))) {
      mmm <- .Internal(pmin(na.rm, ...))
      mostattributes(mmm) <- attributes(elts[[1L]])
   }
```

That part of the code it seems is intended for when the values for `pmin` are vectors and the latter part takes care of the case where you might have a `data.frame`, but it fails in this given scenario.

Comment: It's a little deeper than just one line. `each` gets repeated up to the length of `mmm`: `each <- rep(each, length.out = l2)` where `l2 = length(mmm)` (when `mmm` is a data frame, this is the number of columns). And `each` is a `list`, not a value.

Comment: It's tricky too that `pmin` seems to be designed to work symmetrically, `pmin(x, y)` and `pmin(y, x)` returning the same result. I think it fair to say it was never intended for use on data frames - though throwing an error rather than a confusing result would probably be better.

Comment: @Gregor - that would be my thought. If it isn't two (or n) vectors, or two (or n) data.frames/matrices of the exact same dimensions, it should throw an Error.

Comment: @Gregor. Yes, in general it is as you mentioned. I only address the specific example above. I think it is reasonable to expect it to work for data.frame and I suspect that the code is intended for it to work or perhaps it was meant for matricies. Because otherwise it seems that you can do with just the first half of the code.

Comment: @thelatemail I agree that in general it should throw an error. In the case of a single number I do think it should be the exception as it is a very common case. So I would expect it treat as if it is a vector of the same length.

Comment: It works for matrices (they are handled in the first bit of code because they are just vectors with 2 dimensions). I think the rest of the code is to handle certain S4 classes (though I have no idea which ones).